# My texture is refusing to apply to my model, even though I properly applied it in the shading menu

Tags: texturing

Through importing my texture I created with texture paint and attached its color to the base color of the Principled BSDF, it should make the texture show up as it has in the past, but it won't anymore.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your model UV mapped?  If so, would you post a screenshot of that, and of the image you're trying to use?  Also, it can be a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem, and the image packed. The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: I sent the image of the UV wrap

Comment: The screenshot shows the image name as "Phone", not Phone.jpg or Phone.png -- did you paint this in Blender?  If so, have you tried saving the image and opening that file in the Image Texture node?

Comment: I did paint it in Blender, and I am unsure whether or not I have opened it in the Image Texture node, how do I?

Comment: I figured it out, it was connected to two images, one of which was a blank image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it was connected to two images, one of which was a blank image.